# How do I see that the sequence $\{\chi_{[n, n+1]}\} \to 0$ in probability?

Tags: real-analysis

On $\mathbb{R}$, a sequence measurable functions $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to a measurable function $f$ in probability if for every $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of finite measure and every $\eta > 0$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} m(\{x \in F \mid |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|> \eta\})=0$$

How can I show that the sequence $\{\chi_{[n, n+1]}\} \to 0$ in probability?

I can show that the sequence doesn't converge in measure to $0$, but it's a bit tricky I believe to prove convergence in probability.

Comment: What is $m$? Is it Lebesgue measure? If so, what is the probability measure? It seems to be something like $m(E) := m(E \cap F) /m(F)$ for $F$ such that $m(F) < \infty$....

Comment: @DrewBrady: Yes, sorry, it's Lebesgue measure. And I'm not understanding the rest of your comment.

Comment: Well you said something "converges in probability." Just so you understand what is happening is we are thinking of for each $F$, defining a probability measure by $p_F(E) := \tfrac{m(E\cap F)}{m(F)}$. It is easily seen that $p_F$ defines a probability measure. Then your limit relation is nothing but the standard notion of convergence in probability for $p_F$. You are just requiring this for all $F$ for which this definition makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for providing context. I didn't knew that. This problem comes from an old exam question that I'm trying to answer and there wasn't any more information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to observe that $m(F)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} m(F \cap [n,n+1))<\infty$ which implies that $m(F \cap [n,n+1)) \to 0$.

Note that $m(\{x \in F:|\chi_{[n,n+1]}-0|>\eta\} =m(F\cap [n,n+1])$ for any $\eta >0$.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please explain how then does the conclusion follow? Maybe it's obvious but I just don't see it. Thank you.

Comment: if $\sum_n a_n < \infty$, then $a_n \to 0$; this is a classical fact from analysis (easily seen by considering the tail sum)

Comment: I can see that, but I want to prove that $m(\{x \in F \mid |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|>\eta\}) \to 0$ and the sets don't seem a like to me.

Comment: @JohnSmith $$\{x \in F \mid |\chi_{[n, n+1]}(x)-0|> \eta\}=F\cap[n,n+1].$$

Comment: @JohnSmith I have added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you @Feng, and @ geetha290krm

Comment: Can I ask how was I supposed to see that the two sets are the same? I'm not sure if I would've guessed these two are equal without being explicitly told so.

Comment: If characteristic function of  a set $A$ is strictly greater than $0$  at a point $x$ then  it must be equal to $1$ and the point has to belong to $A$.  @JohnSmith

Comment: @geetha290krm That makes so much sense when said that way. Thank you once again for your help.